# Electric field lines of dielectric sphere in uniform field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, vector-fields, dielectric

I need equation of an electric field lines of dielectric sphere in uniform field (out of sphere) in polar coordinated to drawing it with TikZ. The differential equations which I get is very complex. Can anyone show me the source, where I can find solution of equations?

Comment: If you need the solution to a differential equation, then [Mathematics SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/) is the place to ask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving the potential function for a Dielectric Sphere in a constant Electric Field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/338569)

Comment: @sammygerbil Thank you, I know this solution. I need to get from it equation of field line (in polar coordinates)  for drawing.